# Click not recognized on element with dynamically added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, addclass

I have the following javascript object:

```
TeamExpand = {
    trigger: '.team-info h2.initial',
    container: '.team-info',
    closeTrigger: '.team-info h2.expanded',
    init: function() {
       jQuery(this.trigger).click(this.expandInfo.bind(this));
       jQuery(this.closeTrigger).click(this.closeInfo.bind(this));
    },
    expandInfo: function(e) {
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).closest('.team-info').css("height", "100%");
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).removeClass("initial");
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).addClass("expanded");
        jQuery(this.socialSVG).attr("fill", "#ffc40c");
    },
    closeInfo: function(e) {
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).closest('.team-info').css("height", "64px");
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).removeClass("expanded");
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).addClass("initial");
        jQuery(this.socialSVG).attr("fill", "white");
    }
}
```

My html is as follow:

```
<div class="team-info">
    <h2 class="initial">Header</h2>
    <h3>Job Title</h3>
    <p>Bio</p>
</div><!--end team-info-->
```

The 'expandInfo' function is running just fine and changed the 'container' height to 100%;  The 'initial' class is removed from the `h2` and the 'expanded' class is added to the `h2`.  But the click event on the 'closeTrigger' variable (the h2.expanded) element is not registering.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rewrite this a bit to make the event handlers simpler. Use one handler for all the `h2` and just check the class. This way you avoid attaching detaching handlers.

```
TeamExpand = {
    trigger: '.team-info h2',
    container: '.team-info',
    init: function() {
       jQuery(this.trigger).click(this.doTriger.bind(this));
    },
    doTriger: function(e) {
        var element = jQuery(e.currentTarget);
        if (element.hasClass('initial')) {
            this.expandInfo(element);
        } else {
            this.closeInfo(element);
        }
    },
    expandInfo: function(element) {
        element.closest('.team-info').css("height", "100%");
        element.removeClass("initial");
        element.addClass("expanded");
        jQuery(this.socialSVG).attr("fill", "#ffc40c");
    },
    closeInfo: function(element) {
        element.closest('.team-info').css("height", "64px");
        element.removeClass("expanded");
        element.addClass("initial");
        jQuery(this.socialSVG).attr("fill", "white");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jack...Thanks worked great (minus the couple of commas you missed after 'container' variable and doTriger function

Comment: Can you add those commas for anyone future, won't let me as the two commas "are not at least 6 characters" :)

Comment: @JordanBarber Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're applying the click event function to an element that doesn't actually exist (the **h2** element doesn't yet have the *.expanded* class).

Try moving this line of code..

```
jQuery(this.closeTrigger).click(this.closeInfo.bind(this));
```

..to the end of your *expandInfo* function, and add this..

```
jQuery(this.closeTrigger).unbind('click');
```

..to your *closeInfo* function before this line..

```
jQuery(e.currentTarget).removeClass("expanded");
```

Hope this helps!

Full code..

```
TeamExpand = {
    trigger: '.team-info h2.initial',
    container: '.team-info',
    closeTrigger: '.team-info h2.expanded',
    init: function() {
       jQuery(this.trigger).click(this.expandInfo.bind(this));
    },
    expandInfo: function(e) {
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).closest('.team-info').css("height", "100%");
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).removeClass("initial");
        jQuery(this.trigger).unbind('click');
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).addClass("expanded");
        jQuery(this.socialSVG).attr("fill", "#ffc40c");
        jQuery(this.closeTrigger).click(this.closeInfo.bind(this));
    },
    closeInfo: function(e) {
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).closest('.team-info').css("height", "64px");
        jQuery(this.closeTrigger).unbind('click');
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).removeClass("expanded");
        jQuery(e.currentTarget).addClass("initial");
        jQuery(this.socialSVG).attr("fill", "white");
        this.init();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That definitely helped, but it only works once.  I can open expand the info and close it, but it does not work the second time.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not entirely sure why that would be, but I haven't exactly tested the code either. I've updated my answer to include the full code so feel free to give it a try.